# Watemark from the home page

Tags: thesis, watermark

How to remove a 'MODEL' watermark from the home page? Follow the pdf and the preamble.

```
\documentclass[dissertacao,abnt]{inf-ufg}

\usepackage[alf,bibjustif]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.eps}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{\raggedright{\footnotesize \textbf{Fonte}: {#1}}} }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\autor{rsa} % (José da Silva)
\autorR{a, rs} % (da Silva, José)
\titulo{Aplicação da ....}
\cidade{G....} % Nome da cidade em foi desenvolvido o trabalho

\dia{19}%{\textless Dia\textgreater} %
\mes{06}%{\textless Mes\textgreater } % Data da apresentação/defesa do trabalho
\ano{2020} % Formato numérico: \dia{01}, \mes{01} e \ano{2009}
\orientadorR{}
\universidade{Uni....} % {University}
\uni{UNI}         
\unidade{Esc...} %Institute
\programa{Eng...} % Computação
\concentracao{M...}% Área de Concentração
%-------------------------------------------------- ELEMENTOS PRÉ-TEXTUAIS %
\capa    % Gera o modelo da capa externa do trabalho
\publica % Gera a autorização para publicação em formato eletrônico
\rosto   % Primeira folha interna do trabalho

\input{./pre/pre_aprovacao}
\input{./pre/pre_direitos}
\input{./pre/pre_dedicatoria}
\input{./pre/pre_agradecimentos}
\input{./pre/pre_epigrafe}
\input{./pre/pre_resumo}
\input{./pre/pre_abstract}
%
\tabelas[figtab]

%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de Símbolos}
%\chapter*{Lista de Símbolos} \nonumber

% ----- Para fazer lista de siglas --------------------------------------------------------
\input{./siglas/listadesiglas}
% ----- Para fazer lista de símbolos --------------------------------------------------------
\input{./simbolos/simbolos}
%--------------------------------------------------------------- CAPÍTULOS %
\doublespacing

\input{./tex/cap_I_REV02}
\input{./tex/cap_II_REV02}
\input{./tex/cap_III_REV02}
\input{./tex/cap_IV_REV05}
\input{./tex/cap_V_REV05}
\input{./tex/cap_VI_REV02}

%------------------------------------------------------------ BIBLIOGRAFIA %
\cleardoublepage
\arial

\bibliographystyle{abntex2}%Cita o nome 
\bibliography{./bib/modelo-tese} %%% Nomes dos seus arquivos .bib
\label{ref-bib}
%--------------------------------------------------------------- APÊNDICES %
\apendices
\input{./pos/apend_I _dados_nominais_g1_g2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The watermark is printed by the `\modelo` command defined in the class. You can redefine this command to execute `\relax`, i.e., do nothing. In the MWE below this redefinition is provided six lines from the end, just before `\capa` (the front page) is executed.

MWE:

```
% Exemplo de dissertação do INF-UFG com texto em portugues formatado com LaTeX
\documentclass[dissertacao]{inf-ufg}
%----------------------------------------------------- INICIO DO DOCUMENTO %
\begin{document}

%------------------------------------------ AUTOR, TÍTULO E DATA DE DEFESA %
\autor{\textless Nome do Autor do Trabalho\textgreater} % (José da Silva)
\autorR{\textless Nome Reverso do Autor do Trabalho\textgreater} % (da Silva, José)

\titulo{\textless Título do Trabalho\textgreater}
\subtitulo{\textless Subtítulo do Trabalho\textgreater}

\cidade{\textless Cidade\textgreater} % Nome da cidade em foi desenvolvido o trabalho
\dia{\textless Dia\textgreater} %
\mes{\textless Mês\textgreater} % Data da apresentação/defesa do trabalho
\ano{\textless Ano\textgreater} % Formato numérico: \dia{01}, \mes{01} e \ano{2009}

%-------------------------------------------------------------- ORIENTADOR %
\orientador{\textless Nome do Orientador\textgreater}
\orientadorR{\textless Nome Reverso do Orientador\textgreater}
% Use os comandos a seguir se for Orientadora e nao Orientador.
%\orientadora{\textless Nome da Orientadora\textgreater}
%\orientadoraR{\textless Nome Reverso da Orientadora\textgreater}

\coorientador{\textless Nome do Co-orientador\textgreater}
\coorientadorR{\textless Nome Reverso do Co-orientador\textgreater}
% Use os comandos a seguir se for Co-orientadora e nao Coorientador.
%\coorientadora{\textless Nome da Co-orientadora\textgreater}
%\coorientadoraR{\textless Nome Reverso da Co-orientadora\textgreater}

%-------------------------------------------------- INSTITUIÇÃO E PROGRAMA %
\universidade{\textless Nome da Universidade\textgreater} % {Universidade Federal de Goiás}
\uni{\textless Sigla da Universidade\textgreater}         % UFG
\unidade{\textless Nome da Unidade Acadêmica\textgreater} %Instituto de Informática
\departamento{\textless Nome do Departamento\textgreater} %Unidades com mais de um depto.

\universidadeco{\textless Nome da Universidade do Co-orientador\textgreater}
\unico{\textless Sigla da Universidade do Co-orientador\textgreater}
\unidadeco{\textless Nome da Unidade Acadêmica do Co-orientador\textgreater}

\programa{\textless Nome do Programa de Pós-Graduação\textgreater} % Computação
\concentracao{\textless Área de Concentração\textgreater}

%-------------------------------------------------- ELEMENTOS PRÉ-TEXTUAIS %
\renewcommand{\modelo}{\relax}
\capa    % Gera o modelo da capa externa do trabalho
\publica % Gera a autorização para publicação em formato eletrônico
\rosto   % Primeira folha interna do trabalho

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you man! You solved the problem!

Comment: @rsa if he solved your problem please accept it - accepting it the common way of knowing it was helpful and solved the question as well as it is noted by future that "OK. this answer solved this question."